# Checking my understanding of Hash Tables

Tags: python, hashtable, implementation

I'm a first year computer science student.  I am trying to teach myself hash tables for an interview.  After reading a few pieces about them, I thought the best way of seeing if I'd got it would be to implement my own hash table in Python.  So that's what I've done.  Please could somebody look at it and let me know what you think?  Have I correctly understood what it is I am meant to be doing with a hash table?

```
storage_array = []

def show_menu():
    menu_option = int(raw_input("Enter 1 to store data, Enter 2 to retrieve data: "))
    if (menu_option == 1):
        store_data()
    elif (menu_option == 2):
        retrieve_data()

def store_data():
    key_for_data = raw_input("Please enter the key for the data you want to store: ")
    actual_data = raw_input("Please enter the data you want to store: ")
    ascii_count = generate_hash(key_for_data)
    print ascii_count
    storage_array[ascii_count] = actual_data
    print "The data:'", actual_data, "'has been stored at index:'", ascii_count, "' which is the ascii count of:'", key_for_data, "'"
    show_menu()

def retrieve_data():
    key_for_data = raw_input("Enter the key for the data you want to retrieve: ")
    ascii_count = generate_hash(key_for_data)
    if (storage_array[ascii_count] == None):
        print "No data was stored under this key"
    else:
        print "The data you requested for key:'", key_for_data, "'with ASCII count:'", ascii_count, "' is:'", storage_array[ascii_count], "'"
    show_menu()

def generate_hash(input):
    character_list = list(input)
    ascii_count = 0
    for character_index in range(0,len(character_list)):
        ascii_count += ord(character_list[character_index])
    return ascii_count

def initiate_list():
    for repeat_index in range(0,1000):
        storage_array.append(None)
    print "List initiated with index's to 1000"

initiate_list()
show_menu()


##Or is it meant to hash the key like a dictionary and then store
##the value for that key in the hashed value in the hash table?
```

Comment: Please post the code, don't post a screenshot.

Comment: Why?  Isn't a screenshot just as good for checking understanding of a concept?

Comment: You posted a picture of text. Post text instead.

Comment: @Sam What if I want to paste it into my editor and run the Python code myself? What if the code should be indexable by search engines?

Comment: The link to "code" is also an image. Just post the code.

Comment: I get your point in general, but for checking I understand the concept I wouldn't have thought it a problem.  But ok I'll post the code - give me 2 mins.

Comment: Ok - code is at http://samheather.synology.me/Hash Table ASCII.py

Comment: @SamHeather: Just put it in the question next time!

Comment: How did it just get in there now?  Does it automatically copy contents of links?

Comment: and sorry!  I just did a screenshot as it was quicker.  Point taken.

Comment: @SamHeather Someone edited your post (users with a certain reputation don't need approval).

Comment: @SamHeather: No, I did. How is a screenshot quicker? Bet you had to crop it. You can just copy and paste text right in.

Comment: As for the actual question, do you think you should be handling hash collisions?

Comment: This is my first attempt - I wanted to make sure I hadn't mis-understood what a hash table was.  But yes I will adapt it in future if this is correct so far to handle those.

Comment: Your initiate list function can be replaced with the one-liner `storage_array = [None] * 1000`

Comment: @Eric - thanks that's useful to know!  Is there a nice way of making it so the list just grows to the size I need it to be?  E.g. it stars of as [], and then if I add something at index 10 it creates None's up to index 10 and then fills in 10?

Comment: @SamHeather: That kinda defeats the point of a hash table. Hash tables work by taking an infinite number of keys and compressing them into a finite number of hashes.

Comment: @Eric - ah thanks!  I hadn't twigged that part!

Comment: @SamHeather, you need to think about how to store and retrieve many values under the same hash. A simple way is to store a list at each node which you can just do a linear search over. You should choose the size of the hash table  to be large enough (and the hash function) so that those lists are quite small.

Comment: @gnibbler how would I search over it?  Surely all that's stored in the lists is the string data, so it won't be identifiable by key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the general concept correct. The hash table takes an arbitrary key and turns it into an index into an array via some special method.

A couple points:

**First**, and most important: your generate_hash function can return an index that is invalid if the sum of the ord()s of the key is greater than 1000.

To fix this, have generate_hash return `ascii_count % 1000`. If you don't know what `%` means, go read up on the modulus operator (don't worry, it's not too complicated).

**Second**, also important: think about what happens if you use the following two keys: `ab` and `ba`. What you're doing isn't necessarily wrong, but it's important to understand the behavior of your hash table when different keys collide.

**Third**, less important: your for loops don't have to work like they do in C/C++. You could change

```
for character_index in range(0,len(character_list)):
        ascii_count += ord(character_list[character_index])
```

to

```
for character in character_list:
        ascii_count += ord(character)
```

Python for loops are pretty fancy :)

All in all, it looks great!

Answer (score 0):

You have a hashing function (which I assume produces the same hash for the same input) and you use the hash produced from the hashing function on your key as an index into your array to access the data associated with the key, so yes it appears you have the gist of hash tables.

A good thing to keep in mind is that you should choose a hashing function that operates quickly on the input and is written well enough to reasonably avoid collisions (cases where two keys produce the same hash).

Comment: Same as below re: collisions, thanks.  RE: 'operates quickly', is what's I've got something that operates quickly?  How would I work out something that works quickly to something that doesn't in this scenario?

Comment: The "ultimate feature" of hash functions is that they have (mostly) O(1) lookup time, which means that the time that it takes to get a value doesn't depend on the number of things in the hashtable. "Operating quickly" is mostly an extension of that. People use hashtables because they're *fast*, and a lot of time goes into optimizing the hash function that creates the indices. I wouldn't worry too much about the speed of your hash function in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `generate_hash()` function can return hash values that fall outside your table.

You should also have a strategy for dealing with collisions. You will always get collisions eventually with a hash table.

Your generate_hash function can be written more simply

```
def generate_hash(s):
    return sum(ord(c) for c in s)
```

If you use modulus 1000, you can avoid the problem of hash values falling outside the table

```
def generate_hash(s):
    return sum(ord(c) for c in s)%1000
```

`retrieve_data()` has a bug. Because you haven't thought about collisions, If I store something with the key 'ad' I can retrieve it using the key 'cb'

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer.  Just trying to get a really basic understanding first but yes - thanks.

Comment: It's probably worse mentioning that the hash will have lots of collisions. For instance, `generate_hash("ab")` will be the same as `generate_hash("ba")`.

Comment: @Blckknght, it'll have lots of collisions just because the keyspace is quite small. It happens that it's easy to deliberately find collisions with the particular hash being used here.